# Silent failure to write large files in python

Tags: python, io, multiprocessing, large-files, pickle

I have a program that uses `cPickle` to dump large (several GB) files. It appears to work fine for smaller files (the largest file it worked for was 5.6 GB) but fail silently (!) on larger files.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using **multiprocessing** to generate and write these files on several nodes simultaneously. I suspect that this problem is not specific to (c)Pickle as I've experienced similar issues trying to write out large files in `HDF5` using `h4py`.

Any idea what might be going on?

Some additional info:
I'm running on Linux with EXT4 file system. I should have more than enough RAM (60 GB + 120 GB swap ... no MemoryError) and each process works on a separate file. No process gets killed ... I have a loop that calculates a large file on each iteration and dumps it. If the file's too large it just doesn't get dumped and the process goes on the the next iteration of the loop without any error message or any other indication that something went wrong (except the missing file).

Here's a minimal sample that reproduces the behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import cPickle
import multiprocessing as mp

def test():
    test = np.random.random(1000000000)
    # test = np.random.random(10000) # this works
    cPickle.dump(test, open('/home/ctw/tmp/test.pickle','w'), -1)

po = mp.Pool(1)
po.apply_async(test)
po.close()
```

The result is the creation of an empty file. When I run this outside the multiprocessing environment, the usual result is the creation of a small (127B) file and the following error message (I never see an error when I run this using multiprocessing):

```
In [32]: cPickle.dump(test, open('/home/ctw/tmp/test.pickle','w'), -1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-62283b59a617> in <module>()
----> 1 cPickle.dump(test, open('/home/ctw/tmp/test.pickle','w'), -1)

SystemError: error return without exception set
```

Another update: If I use 0 instead of -1 as the protocol, the file gets written.

Comment: Answering this question will be a guess since it lacks info, you can try to run your process using [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#command-line-usage) that may give you some direction to the problem or where it happens, also if you are using multiprocessing try to limit to 1 process (yes it will take more time) but it will tell you if there is some collision between the processes.

Comment: Some `file systems` can have size limitations - for example FAT32 has limit 4GB.

Comment: If you are on a linux system, make sure you're not running out of RAM, as the system may be killing the process

Comment: Sorry about lack of info and thanks for the responses so far. I'm running on Linux with EXT4 file system. I should have more than enough RAM (60 GB + 120 GB swap ... no MemoryError) and each process works on a separate file. No process gets killed ... I have a loop that calculates a large file on each iteration and dumps it. If the file's too large it just doesn't get dumped and the process goes on the the next iteration of the loop without any error message or any other indication that something went wrong (except the missing file).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's an inherent limit on cpickle file sizes for Python <3.3 of 2**31-1 for the byte protocol. Still annoying/strange that there's no error message during multiprocessing.